# Can not verify Smart Contract with @chainlink

Tags: remix, chainlink

I can not verify my test smart contract on BSC Main Network using @chainlink.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceTest {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    
    constructor() public { 
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x0567F2323251f0Aab15c8dFb1967E4e8A7D42aeE); // for BSC Main Net

    }
 
   function getLatestPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (,int price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(price/100000000);
    }
     
}
```

What I have done :

1. Make Flattened file and put in the contract code using truffle-flattener. I did it before for a test net and it's ok.
2. Copy ABI from remix and pasted to abi.hashex.org

But I tried many time end up with problem in verifying the contract. I think I am not really understand how to put constructor parameter correctly to get the ABI auto-parse.
I am quite new to smart contract. Need learn more from experts.

My contract :

https://bscscan.com/address/0x0849a15338a5f0787696cea335757b608ff92a85

Flattened file :

```
// File: @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.6\interfaces\AggregatorV3Interface.sol

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {

  function decimals()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint8
    );

  function description()
    external
    view
    returns (
      string memory
    );

  function version()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint256
    );

  // getRoundData and latestRoundData should both raise "No data present"
  // if they do not have data to report, instead of returning unset values
  // which could be misinterpreted as actual reported values.
  function getRoundData(
    uint80 _roundId
  )
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

}

// File: contracts\Getprice.sol

pragma solidity ^0.6.7;


contract PriceTest {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    
    constructor() public { 
    priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x0567F2323251f0Aab15c8dFb1967E4e8A7D42aeE); // for BSC Main Net

    }
 
   function getLatestPrice() public view returns (uint256) {
        (,int price,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(price/100000000);
    }
     
}
```

Comment: What version did you compile with? Did you try with https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify.

Comment: @Patrick I did trial of verification for several smart contract previously including openzeppelin. Of course I have check the compiler version, optimization, SPDX-License, ABI. But this one make me spent all night and still struggle :)

Comment: @Patric I know you are Chainlink DevRel. I have tried on Rinkeby : priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xcf0f51ca2cDAecb464eeE4227f5295F2384F84ED); // for Rinkeby. Please try this and let me know if you can verify the contract. Thks anyway.

Comment: I'll need to know what compiler version you used to deploy it to verify it, do you know what version you used to compile it? What does your truffle-config look like?

Comment: @Patric Compiler on Remix : 0.6.7+commint.b8d736ae and also tried using 0.6.12+commit.275d51765. I deployed it using REMIX, but I also migrate the same file on my project folder using Truffle to get the ABI stored on my contract. Actually it's works fine. Problem is can not verify the contract.

Comment: @Patric I want to know what is the problem in the future if I deploy a smart contract and it works fine but not doing verification on the explorer? Who will complain and do something bad to my contract? Thx

Comment: BTW verification is Success using 0.6.12+commit.275d51765 on Rinkeby : https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x85E96D9342bec02bEe348E45eC4aeb3aE5f57a06#code

Comment: Perfect! Then you should be able to verify with the same compiler version on BSC